# Where is the right place to put "only"

Tags: adverbs, word-order

I'm unsure where to put the word "only" in the following sentence:

> - The machine must be operated by the authorized personnel from [company X] **only**.
> - The machine must **only** be operated by the authorized personnel from [company X].
> - The machine must be operated **only** by the authorized personnel from [company X].

If there's another way of saying this, let me know.

Comment: All three sentences mean the exact same thing.

Comment: I disagree. The first limits the activity, whatever it is, to company X. The second means limits the activity to operation, as opposed to repair or calibration. The third limits the activity to specific personnel from company X.